Problem Understanding why $P(X\leq kY) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}{P(X\leq ky)}$ is wrong for Y taking positive integer values
I have trouble understanding why the following holds:

Let X, and Y be independent random variables taking values in the positive integers, then
$P(X\leq kY) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}{P(X\leq kY, Y=y)} = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}{P(X\leq ky, Y=y)}$

Whereas what I expected was:
$P(X\leq kY) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}{P(X\leq ky)}$.
I do not understand why we cannot write it this, and instead we have to introduce Y=y inside the probability.
Thank you very much.

It might be useful to present your intuition/logic - why do you think it should be what you expected? You've already received answers for why it cannot be the case, but I suspect there's a deeper misunderstanding of the concept here.

I am going to try and retrace your steps first, to see how you might have arrived at what you expect, and where the flaw in your reasoning is. I've expanded your argument to use 4 expressions to highlight exactly where the flaws are.
Argument:
$P(X \leq kY) \stackrel{?}{=} \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P((X \leq kY) \ \cap (X \leq ky)) \stackrel{?}{=} \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P(X \leq kY)P(X \leq ky)  \stackrel{?}{=} \sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P(X \leq ky)$
There are a few flaws here

The correct claim uses the law of total probability. The idea behind using LOTP is to partition a messy event ($X \leq kY $) into smaller, more manageable events ($X \leq k, X \leq 2k, X \leq 3k ...$). Your chosen breakdown of events does not form a partition, and in any case, it is not a useful partition. Since it does not form a partition, you cannot move from expression 1 to expression 2 - you violate the axioms of probability by doing so.

The intermediate statements do not really have a meaning. This becomes obvious when you rewrite your expected statement (expression 1 = expression 3) as


$P(X \leq kY) = P(X \leq kY)\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P(X \leq ky)$.
I can just take out the $P(X \leq kY)$ term because it is not a part of the sum at all - $Y$ does not depend on $y$ in your formulation! It is evident that something has gone wrong when you simplify this to get $\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P(X \leq ky) = 1$ - this is not true, as Davide pointed out, because the term inside the summation converges to 1, so the sum does not converge at all.

The leap from expression 2 to expression 3 assumes that the event $X \leq kY$ is independent of $X \leq ky$. Is this true? Since $Y$ and $y$ are unrelated in your formulation, I can just set $y$ to be arbitrarily large, and that will lead to $P(X \leq kY | X \leq y) = 1 $.

The leap from expression 3 to 4 is beyond me - a term has vanished from the sum and I'm not sure why. Is it equal to 1? Does it cancel out? In both those cases, you see there's something wrong.


You can see that there is no singular error - the errors compound.

I'll write down a step-by-step breakdown of the original claim so you can see which theorems/techniques have been used to arrive the final expression.
$P(X \leq kY)$
= $P(\bigcup\limits_{y=1}^{\infty} ((X \leq kY) \cap (Y = y)))$ [Partition of disjoint sets]
= $\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P(X \leq kY, Y = y)$ [By axioms of probability]
= $\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P(Y = y)P(X \leq kY | Y = y)$ [Conditioning on $Y = y$]
= $\sum\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}P(Y = y)P(X \leq ky)$  [$(X \leq kY | Y = y) = (X \leq ky)]$

@cangozpi - you're right, i made a mistake. fixed it, sorry about that!

Thank you very much for your help, your explanation was great !

First of all, $\lim_{y\to\infty} P(X\leq ky)=1$ hence the series cannot converge.
The role of the sets $\{Y=y\}$ is to decompose the event $\{X\leq kY\}$ as a union of pairwise disjoint events, namely, $\{X\leq kY\}=\bigcup_{y=1}^\infty (\{X\leq kY\}\cap\{Y=y\})$.

Suppose your formula is true. For example, take $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. with
$$\mathbb P(X=1)=1-\mathbb P(X=2)=1/2$$
Then, for $k=1$, you would have
$$\mathbb P(X\leqslant Y)=\mathbb P(X\leqslant 1)+\mathbb P(X\leqslant 2)=3/2>1$$
which is clearly not true.
